# Non immutable class visibility in the normal method after being published in the synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

In the below `Service` class, `Conf` object gets created and published  in the `synchronized` method `latestConf()` (ignoring `init()` as it is called by only one thread).

But it is always read in the normal (non-synchronized) method `serve()`.

Does the above process make sure `serve()` method always reading the properly published `Conf` object? or do i need to `synchronize` the `serve()` method also?

```
public class Service
{
  private Conf conf;

  private static class Conf
  {
    private String s1, s2;

    Conf(String s1, String s2)
    {
      this.s1 = s1;
      this.s2 = s2;
    }

    // Getters for s1 and s2
  }

  // 1. Called only once
  public void init()
  {
    this.conf = loadConf();
  }

  // 2. Called by multiple threads after init()
  public void serve()
  {
    Conf latestConf = latestConf();
    System.out.println(latestConf);
  }

  private synchronized Conf latestConf()
  {
    if (!needToReloadConfiguration())
      return this.conf;

    Conf latestConf = loadConf();
    this.conf = latestConf;
    return latestConf;
  }

  private boolean needToReloadConfiguration()
  {
    // check if configuration needs to be reloaded
  }

  private Conf loadConf()
  {
    String s1 = ...;
    String s2 = ...;
    return new Conf(s1, s2);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, serve() doesn't read this.conf. It calls latestConf(), that returns a Conf, and reads the returned value. So it doesn't read any published object. Yes, it's safe. Your Conf class should be final and its fields final, too.

Comment: @JBNizet 2nd time (when there is no need to reload the `Conf`) it reads from `this.conf`

Comment: No, it doesn't. latestConf() is the one reading this.conf. And it's synchronized. serve() gets its conf from latestConf(), which is synchronized. It doesn't even know there is a conf field.

Comment: Yes. Got it :).

Comment: @JBNizet >> `Your Conf class should be final and its fields final, too.` Yes. I want to learn about the case what happens when the class  and its fields are non final (but the class is not mutable - no setters), because i'm using `synchronized` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But it is always read in the normal (non-synchronized) method serve().

This would be a problem except that `serve()` was accessing the `conf` field directly.  However it is calling `latestConf()` which is `synchronized` so you are fine.

If you make the `conf` field be `volatile` then you can access it directly in `serve()` without having the `synchronized` block.  Assigning to `this.conf` will cross a write memory barrier and reading from `this.conf` will cross a read memory barrier ensuring safe publishing of `conf`.

However, you need the `synchronized` block if you need to test each time to see if the configuration needs to be updating.  Another idea would be to fork a thread which updates the configuration in the background whenever needed so the worker threads would just get the configuration and it would be guaranteed to by the most up-to-date because of the `volatile`.

Also, as @JBNizet also points out, making the fields in `Conf` be `final` is always a very good pattern because it ensures that the constructor will fully initialize the fields before it results.  You don't *need* to do this if you are using `synchronized` or `volatile` for every access but it's a good pattern.

Comment: if i don't use `snchronized` more than one thread can check `needToReloadConfiguration()` and try to create the `Conf` object

Comment: Often if the testing of the update and the actual creating of the configuration data is cheap, I'll forgo the locks and just figure that if they actually overlap then they will just make it twice.